# Custom font not showing when file and file path are correct

Tags: java

```
***
Text text = new Text("MENU");
Font font = (Font.loadFont("file:resources/fonts/Italic.ttf", 120));
text.setFont(font);
***
```

I have tried so many ways to do this but the font is simply not showing up. I'm not getting any error or anything the text is just staying default font.

Comment: why do you think that file path is correct?

Comment: Does resources>fonts>Italic.ttf not equal file:resources/fonts/Italic.ttf? @IłyaBursov

Comment: I just added "src/" haha my bad.